# Go lang RPC return EOF error

Tags: go, json-rpc

I'm using http to call RPC with code below

```
func (c *CallClient) Wallet(method string, req, rep interface{}) error {
    client := &http.Client{}
    data, _ :=  EncodeClientRequest(method, req)
    reqest, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", c.endpoint, bytes.NewBuffer(data))
    resp, err := client.Do(reqest)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    return DecodeClientResponse(resp.Body, rep)
}
```

with EncodeClientRquest && DecodeClientResponse

// EncodeClientRequest encodes parameters for a JSON-RPC client request.

```
func EncodeClientRequest(method string, args interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    c := &clientRequest{
        Version: "2.0",
        Method: method,
        Params: [1]interface{}{args},
        Id:     uint64(rand.Int63()),
    }

    return json.Marshal(c)
}
```

// DecodeClientResponse decodes the response body of a client request into
// the interface reply.

```
func DecodeClientResponse(r io.Reader, reply interface{}) error {
    var c clientResponse
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r).Decode(&c); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if c.Error != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%v", c.Error)
    }
    if c.Result == nil {
        return errors.New("result is null")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(*c.Result, reply)
}
```

And I got error EOF.

Comment: Two suggestions to get started: 1) don't ignore errors 2) log the raw request and response.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
```

reads the *whole* `resp.Body`, leaving the reader with no more bytes to be read. Therefore any successive calls to `resp.Body.Read` will return **EOF** and the `json.Decoder.Decode` method does use the `io.Reader.Read` method when decoding the given reader's content, so...

And since `resp.Body` is an `io.ReadCloser`, which is an interface that does not support "rewinding", and you want to read the body content more than once (ioutil.Discard and json.Decode), you'll have to read the body into a variable that you can re-read afterwards. It's up to you how you do that, a slice of bytes, or `bytes.Reader`, or something else.

Example using `bytes.Reader`:

```
func (c *CallClient) Wallet(method string, req, rep interface{}) error {
    client := &http.Client{}
    data, err := EncodeClientRequest(method, req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    reqest, err := http.NewRequest("POST", c.endpoint, bytes.NewBuffer(data))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(reqest)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // get a reader that can be "rewound"
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    if _, err := io.Copy(buf, resp.Body); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    br := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())

    if _, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, br); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // rewind
    if _, err := br.Seek(0, 0); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return DecodeClientResponse(br, rep)
}
```